# How can I convince the architect to allow me to format code?

Tags: formatting, dotnet-format

In our team there is a refactoring sprint where we are allowed to refractor the code base. Now I discovered formatting with 'dotnet format' which automatically formats the whole solution.

The architect in our team has a pretty strong opinion about it and says that one must not do it because it makes the git history less comparable and that one must format one's code always when one commits it. I know about git hooks and that is my preferred work around but I wonder whether I am in the wrong by thinking that a consistently formatted code base leads to avoiding merge conflicts and bugs in the future are benefits that outweighs the possibility to easily use git blame.

I tried to confice the architect and showed him several use cases where a formatted code would help, for example when searching through it via regex.